# HttpListener cannot start process after receive Request [C#]

Tags: javascript, c#, process, permissions, postman

im using system.net.httplistener to listen client requests, i start a process after receive request, the process do stuff and then return a response, using **postman** the process is started properly but wen i use **XMLHttpRequest** on **javascript** (with the same headers and body as the postman request) the process does not start. Using logfile the httplistener application reach the "*p.Start();*" line but does not start.
Do i need some specific header or body value? i think is about permissions but im not sure
Can you help me?

There is the Client Script code

```
function scan(path,foil) {


  var url = "http://localhost:1300/ServicioEscaner/"; //direccion a donde se realiza el request
    var method = "POST";    

    var shouldBeAsync = true; 
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();  


    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
       if ( request.readyState ==  request.DONE) {
        if ( request.status === 200) {
                alert(request.responseText);
        }
      }
    }


    request.open(method, url, shouldBeAsync);

    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

    request.send(JSON.stringify(    {
        "config":
        {
            "tag":
            {
                "value":foil,
                "path":path,
                "type":"scann"
            }
        }
    }));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried adding `[FromBody]` attribute to method parameter?